# Notepad++ Regex Find all endline without periods

Tags: regex, notepad

I'm trying to find all lines without ending period (dot) but without finding blank (empty) lines. And after that I want to add ending period to that sentence. 
Example:

```
The good is whatever stops such things from happening.

Meaning as the Higher Good

It was from this that I drew my fundamental moral conclusions.
```

I have tried few regex but they also find empty lines as well.
Is there a regex for Notepad++ that can achieve that?

Comment: Sure there is a way, post your regex to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Regular Expression match, then search for:

```
\S(?<!\.)\K\s*$
```

and replace with:

```
.$0
```

Breakdown:

- `\S` Match a non-whitespace character
- `(?<!\.)` It shouldn't be a period
- `\K` Reset match
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace characters
- `$` End of line

Comment: In "replace with" for some reason it does not add dot, just skips to the next line.

Comment: Did you click `replace all` button? What changes are made after doing so?

Comment: Thank you revo! It works as intended. My fault: I was using "find next" instead of "select all" and than "replace all".

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to find the lines that you are interested in adding capture group to it and appending you needed chars.

```
(?<!\.)\r\n
```

This works by using negative look behind `(?<!\.)` to check that there is no `.` before `\r`

There is a group or regex operators that can be used to accomplish this type of tasks.

- Look ahead positive (?=)
- Look ahead negative (?!)
- Look behind positive (?<=)
- Look behind negative (?

Comment: It finds blank surplus lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this short and effective solution too.

Search: `\w$`

Replace: `$0.`

[image: a fresh screenshot of my notepadmm Didn't add a dot to new line]